# I am trying to remove required from input field when checkbox is unchecked in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the `required` property from input field when the checkbox is unchecked but it's not working and when the checkbox is checked field should be required please help me thanks.

**html view**

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="checkbox"  id="scheduledis"  name="checkbox[0]" class="schedule_discount"   value="" > 
  <label for=""> Schedule Discount
  </label> 
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-autoclose-1 dislay-required"  required   placeholder="Start Date"  value=""  name="start_date"  >
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <i class="md md-event-note">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('date') ?? null}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**jquery script**

```
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
//check if check if checked 
 $(this).is(':checked') ? 
 
  $('input[name=start_date]').prop('required', false) :
  $('input[name=start_date]').prop('required', true);

  $('input[name=end_date]').prop('required', false) :
  $('input[name=end_date]').prop('required', true);

  $('input[name=start_time]').prop('required', false) :
  $('input[name=start_time]').prop('required', true);

  $('input[name=end_time]').prop('required', false) :
  $('input[name=end_time]').prop('required', true);

});
```

Comment: Can you make it a runnable snippet here on SO?  Use sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if the checkbox is `checked` then use `prop('required', false)` or `prop('required', true)` to remove or add required attribute from input box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  //check if check if checked 
  $(this).is(':checked') ?
    $('input.dislay-required').prop('required', false) :
    $('input.dislay-required').prop('required', true);

});
```

```css
:required {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="scheduledis" name="checkbox[0]" class="schedule_discount" value="">
  <label for=""> Schedule Discount
  </label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-autoclose-1 dislay-required" required placeholder="Start Date" value="" name="start_date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-autoclose-1 dislay-required" required placeholder="End Date" value="" name="end_date">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <i class="md md-event-note">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it's using for a single input field but i want to applying for more then one input field it's not working please guide me how can i do ?thanks.

Comment: all input fields with class `dislay-required` ? If yes updated my answer have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="newmyCheck">NewCheckbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="declinecontact" onclick="mycheckfunc()">
<br><br>
<form>
NAME: <input type="text" id="Personfirstname"><br><br>
SUBMIT: <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
mycheckfunc();
function mycheckfunc(){

    var checkBox = document.getElementById("declinecontact");
     var firstname = document.getElementById("Personfirstname");
   
   
     if (checkBox.checked == true){
         firstname.required = false;
  
      } else {
        firstname.required = true;
    
      }
    }
```